# Do critical characters of a python encoding ever come outside of quotes?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, grammar, lexical-analysis

I was working on a [python scanner library](https://w71.eu/txi0955/?page_id=35) and came across *encodings*. I guess, a lexical scanner will never have problems with 'critical' characters because they always come inside quoted strings. I.e. in unicode, the extra characters are of the form

```
   0x00000000 - 0x0000007F:
       0xxxxxxx

   0x00000080 - 0x000007FF:
       110xxxxx 10xxxxxx

   0x00000800 - 0x0000FFFF:
       1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx

   0x00010000 - 0x001FFFFF:
       11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx

   0x00200000 - 0x03FFFFFF:
       111110xx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx

   0x04000000 - 0x7FFFFFFF:
       1111110x 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

, thus with a code always above x80: they will not mix with ' and ". 
I do not have to care about the encoding. Am I right or not?

References:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding

Answer (score 0):

There are other encodings, where this simple assumption isn't true. For most one byte encodings, this seems to be correct, but for most multi byte encodings other than utf-8 this is definitely wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I am reassured that utf-8 and  [ISO/IEC 8859](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) (15 sets) will need no changes to process the python source. For other encodings, I will have to examine further.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think that oddly encoded characters only appear in strings.

I would expect Python to allow Unicode characters in identifiers.   Then a UTF-8 encoded file (which is apparantly what you are exhibiting here) would have such sequences in identifiers.

I think you also make the mistake that only UTF-8 is usable as an encoding.  I don't know how much Python is used in Japan, but if it is, I would expect a SHIFT-JIS (multibyte character) encoding would be commonly used.

You also need to worry about odd character codes.  For instance, 0x85 in Unicode is a "Newline" character.   Should you treat it as a line break?  To add to your troubles, if you have other character encodings (there are dozens), you will some with 0x85 as a character code, but that doesn't make that into Unicode NEL.

Finally you have the problem of *detecting* the character set.  Python can explicitly specify it in a source file comment at the start of file, but it may also be implicit.   It may also be surprising; apparently there is a version of Python ported to IBM System Z mainframe; in that world, EBCDIC is the preferred character set and codes 0b10xxxxxx correspond to what you think of as lower case alpha letters.

Handling character encodings in source files is real pain, and there are no easy answers if you want to do it right.

My company builds tools to process computer source code (see bio).  The way we handle this is to:

- determine the character encoding before reading the file
  (sometimes by pre-reading the file, e.g., to sniff for UTF-8)
- reading the file and translating all codes into (16 bit) Unicode.

Then at least we only have worry about what the Unicode interpretation of that characters are.